# Dealing with images in R stored as text string

Tags: r

I got the data from SQL Server into R and one of the column in a table is coded as: `[DentalImage]`, the Data Type of this column is `varbinary(MAX)`,
for example one record:

```
0x630000000E00000008020000000000000000000000000000080200000A0000000000000000000000080200001400000000000000000000000002000028000000000000000000000008000000820000000000000000000000080200008C00000000000000000000000802000096000000000000000000000008000000E8030000000000000000000008000000F2030000000000000000000008000000FC030000000000000000000000000000600400000000000000000000080000006A040000000000000000000008000000740400000000000000000000080000007E04000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

How could I view the image in R and what are the possibilities of analyzing such image? I know it's a image of patient's teeth condition containing 32 teeth with several indicators.

Tried to google, but couldn't find anything useful.

Thank you!

Comment: I'm unable to find any images in your given string, it is returned as **application/octet-stream**.

Comment: @mhovd Is there any way of opening/viewing it? Is it just some kind of code for a program which could generate something from it? The original image is not really an image, my mistake it's more like and interactive image/graphic.

Comment: That depends entirely on how the string was generated. Which software, and which method produced the string from the image? Any interactivity is 100% lost.

Comment: If it is a medical image, it is most likely stored in a DICOM format. Maybe the R pacakge *oro.dicom* will be of help.